# Creating new entity associate with an existing entity in EntityType field

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

I'm working on Symfony 3 with Doctrine. In my project for a music school, I have 3 entities (Morceau (translation of Tune), Eleve (translation of Student), Instrument). With one form, I would like to create new Morceau associate with new Eleve associate with an existing Instrument.

Now, I have a problem to associate Eleve with an existing Instrument which is an EntityType (list of all the music instruments):

*Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\Instrument could not be converted to string*

The thing is that I don't want to create a new Instrument id.

The associations are: Morceau (with @ORM/ManyToOne $eleve), Eleve(@ORM/ManyToOne $instrument), Instrument (with $id and $nomInstrument).

My Forms:

MorceauType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('titre', TextType::class)
            ->add('compositeur', TextType::class)
            ->add('formation', TextType::class)
            ->add('duree', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('materiel', TextType::class)
            ->add('accompagnementPiano', ChoiceType::class, 
                array('choices' => array('Oui' => True, 'Non' => False)))   
            ->add('eleve', EleveType::class) 
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)    ;
}
```

EleveType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('nomEleve', TextType::class)
            ->add('prenomEleve', TextType::class)
            ->add('instrument', InstrumentType::class)
                                ;
}
```

InstrumentType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('nomInstrument', EntityType::class, array('class' => 'AppBundle:Instrument', 
                                                                        'choice_label' => 'nomInstrument'))
    ;
}
```

My Controller:

```
public function addTuneAction(Request $request)
{   

    // On récupère le formulaire Morceaux
    $morceau = new Morceau();


    $form = $this->createForm(MorceauType::class, $morceau);

    //On vérifie les valeurs
    if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {  
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($morceau);
        $em->flush();

        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Morceau enregistré');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
    }

    // on retourne la vue
    return $this->render('snippets/addTune.html.twig', array('morceau' => $form->createView()));
}
```

Many thanks !

Here's my entities:

Morceau:

```
/**
 * Morceau
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Morceau")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\MorceauRepository")
 */
class Morceau
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="titre", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $titre;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="compositeur", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $compositeur;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="formation", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $formation;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="duree", type="smallint")
 */
private $duree;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="materiel", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $materiel;

/**
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="accompagnementPiano", type="boolean")
 */
private $accompagnementPiano;

/**
*
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Eleve", cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="eleve_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $eleve;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set titre
 *
 * @param string $titre
 *
 * @return morceau
 */
public function setTitre($titre)
{
    $this->titre = $titre;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get titre
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitre()
{
    return $this->titre;
}

/**
 * Set compositeur
 *
 * @param string $compositeur
 *
 * @return morceau
 */
public function setCompositeur($compositeur)
{
    $this->compositeur = $compositeur;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get compositeur
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCompositeur()
{
    return $this->compositeur;
}

/**
 * Set formation
 *
 * @param string $formation
 *
 * @return morceau
 */
public function setFormation($formation)
{
    $this->formation = $formation;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get formation
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFormation()
{
    return $this->formation;
}

/**
 * Set duree
 *
 * @param integer $duree
 *
 * @return morceau
 */
public function setDuree($duree)
{
    $this->duree = $duree;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get duree
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getDuree()
{
    return $this->duree;
}

/**
 * Set materiel
 *
 * @param string $materiel
 *
 * @return morceau
 */
public function setMateriel($materiel)
{
    $this->materiel = $materiel;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get materiel
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMateriel()
{
    return $this->materiel;
}

/**
 * Set accompagnementPiano
 *
 * @param boolean $accompagnementPiano
 *
 * @return morceau
 */
public function setAccompagnementPiano($accompagnementPiano)
{
    $this->accompagnementPiano = $accompagnementPiano;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get accompagnementPiano
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function getAccompagnementPiano()
{
    return $this->accompagnementPiano;
}

/**
 * Set eleve
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Eleve $eleve
 *
 * @return Morceau
 */
public function setEleve(\AppBundle\Entity\Eleve $eleve = null)
{
    $this->eleve = $eleve;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get eleve
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Eleve
 */
public function getEleve()
{
    return $this->eleve;
}
```

}

Eleve:

```
/**
 * eleve
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Eleve")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\EleveRepository")
 */
class Eleve
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nomEleve", type="string", length=30)
 */
private $nomEleve;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="prenomEleve", type="string", length=50)
 */
private $prenomEleve;

/**
*
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Instrument", cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="instrument_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $instrument;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set nomEleve
 *
 * @param string $nomEleve
 *
 * @return eleve
 */
public function setNomEleve($nomEleve)
{
    $this->nomEleve = $nomEleve;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nomEleve
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getNomEleve()
{
    return $this->nomEleve;
}

/**
 * Set prenomEleve
 *
 * @param string $prenomEleve
 *
 * @return eleve
 */
public function setPrenomEleve($prenomEleve)
{
    $this->prenomEleve = $prenomEleve;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get prenomEleve
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPrenomEleve()
{
    return $this->prenomEleve;
}

/**
 * Set instrument
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Instrument $instrument
 *
 * @return Eleve
 */
public function setInstrument(\AppBundle\Entity\Instrument $instrument)
{
    $this->instrument = $instrument;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get instrument
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Instrument
 */
public function getInstrument()
{
    return $this->instrument;
}
```

}

Instrument:

```
/**
 * Instrument
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Instrument")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\InstrumentRepository")
 */
class Instrument
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nomInstrument", type="string", length=50)
 */
private $nomInstrument;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set nomInstrument
 *
 * @param string $nomInstrument
 *
 * @return instrument
 */
public function setNomInstrument($nomInstrument)
{
    $this->nomInstrument = $nomInstrument;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nomInstrument
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getNomInstrument()
{
    return $this->nomInstrument;
}
```

}

UPDATE #1:

When I look at the Profiler, I can see the problem. If you look at nomInstrument, it's a integer but it should be a string for my entity. In this example, 3 is the id of the Instrument selected...

```
appbundle_morceau : [▼
  "titre" => "Leapfrog"
  "compositeur" => "Ravel"
  "formation" => "duo"
  "duree" => "5"
  "materiel" => "micro"
  "accompagnementPiano" => "1"
  "eleve" => [▼
    "nomEleve" => "Georges"
    "prenomEleve" => "Gauthier"
    "instrument" => [▼
      "nomInstrument" => "3"
    ]
  ]
  "save" => ""
  "_token" => "m3priXJyFUHCGpP58twZx3yyeS1eb-yeWGtIWrv6Llc"
]
```

UPDATE #2:

When I try to do the same action without the form, it works. I set the values in the controller like that:

```
public function testAction(Request $request)
{

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                       ->getManager()
                       ->getRepository('AppBundle:Instrument');

    $instrumentId = $repository->find(3);

    $morceau = new Morceau();
    $eleve = new Eleve();

    $eleve->setNomEleve('Alex');
    $eleve->setPrenomEleve('Jean');
    $eleve->setInstrument($instrumentId);

    $morceau->setTitre('Bolero');
    $morceau->setCompositeur('Ravel');
    $morceau->setFormation('duo');
    $morceau->setDuree('4');
    $morceau->setMateriel('pupitre');
    $morceau->setAccompagnementPiano(true);
    $morceau->setEleve($eleve);



    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($morceau);
    $em->flush();
```

Comment: Sounds like you might have an error with your entity associations - can you post your entities?

Comment: I've added my entities. Thanks.

Comment: My reflexion is that when I do `$morceau = new morceau()`, with the associations that creates a `new Eleve()`and a `new Instrument()`, isn't it ? But I don't want to create a `new Instrument()`, I just want to attached the `new Eleve()`with an Instrument id. Maybe I have to do something like `$form->getData()` and then `setInstrument()` ? or work on the setter of `$instrument`in my Eleve entity... or something else, but I don't know...

Comment: Your `@ManyToOne` annotation in your Eleve entity should have an associated`@Orm\JoinColumn` that conveys how the two entities are related.  If you check your Symfony profiler it's probably throwing warnings about invalid entities.

Comment: Thanks but I try it and it doesn't work... I've add the POST PARAMETERS of the profiler the end of my questions...

Comment: I don't think your post parameter is the problem; it's good that it's an id, it means that it's relating to an existing instrument.  I really think you need the `@ORM\JoinColumn` to associate the two entities.

Comment: Thank you Jason, I have added `@ORM\JoinColumn`(as you can see in my entities) but I have the same `__toSrting()` error...

Comment: I would try recreating your entities and let Doctrine do the auto-generation, then compare to your entities and see where they differ

Comment: I tried it but I have the same error. When I do the same action without the form, it works. You can see that in my new edit _UPDATE #2_

Comment: Have you set `data_class` on all 3 of your form type classes?

Comment: My `data_class` are OK!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long days, I have the solution. I just have to remove my `InstrumentType` and put the `EntityType` directly in my `EleveType`, like that:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('nomEleve', TextType::class)
                ->add('prenomEleve', TextType::class)
                ->add('instrument', EntityType::class, array('class' => 'AppBundle:Instrument', 
                                                                            'choice_label' => 'nomInstrument'))
                                    ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When loading an Entity into a form you need to make sure your Entity class has a `__toString()` method. This is what Symfony uses for the "name" field of `option` elements.

Comment: Thanks, but when I add a `__toString()`method to Instrument, Doctrine creates a `new Instrument()`... My entity Instrument just contains 2 attributes: `$id` and `$nomInstrument` and what I want is that when an instrument is selected in the form (EntityType), my `new Eleve()`created will be associate with the `$id` of the existing Instrument and not with a new Instrument...if it's possible...